# Is it better to use a 403 response or 404?

Tags: database, mongodb, http

I have a restAPI which allows for users to submit data to be saved in my database. When data is submitted their userID will be grabbed from the request header and added to the document

In my collection (mongoDB) there is the normal `_id` field and a `userID` field, which references the user.

My question is in the scenario that a malicious user submits a PUT or DELETE request to a document that does not belong to them what is the best way to handle it.

1. I pull the prediction from the DB just using the submitted `_id`, check the `userID` field against the requesting `userID` and issue a 403 response if they do not match.
2. I query the database by both `_id` and `userID`, so it would not be found if the document does not belong to the requesting user. I would then issue a 404 response just as if they had submitted an id that does not exist.

Both choices achieve the same goal, which is to prevent a user from editing or deleting a resource that does not belong to them, but which is "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 is for "not found", which is clearly not the case.

Use 403.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403):

> HTTP 403 is returned when the client is not permitted access to the resource despite providing authentication ...

Comment: OTOH it does leak the existence of the resource. This lets malicious users probe to find out which IDs exist.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's only the case if ids are guessable, and that's the reason APIs shouldn't use "predictable" ids (eg incrementing numbers). If ids are say UUIDs, nothing could be leaked. The [chance of guessing a UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) if you make 1000 attempts per second for 3000 straight years is less than 1 in a billion.

Answer (score 0):

I would return `403` if user A has permission to view a resource that belongs to user B (as they are already aware of the existence of this resource). Otherwise, I would return `404` for privacy reasons. This is in line with the [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-403-forbidden) standard:

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of 404 (Not Found).